# Why I cannot see Mirroring sheet in Microsoft Fabrics?

Tags: microsoft-fabric

I would like to see mirror Azure SQL, but cannot see Mirroring options workspace in Microsoft Fabric (trial 60 days). Does anybody know how to enable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mirroring is still in private preview and you would have to submit a form to MSFT to be a part of that. Because of this you are unable to see mirror feature

Comment: I wonder if I can apply for private preview with trial account.

Answer (score 1):

As previously mentioned, **mirroring** features are still in **Private Preview** which explains why they're not yet displayed and available in **Microsoft Fabric - Data Warehouse** experience. So guess we have to be a bit more patient as *Microsoft* announced they should be available in **2024 Q1** i.e. within the next couple of months...