# How to Create a Simple SQL Server and Database in Microsoft Fabric

Tags: azure-sql-database, microsoft-fabric

Can someone let me know if it's actually possible to create a simple SQL Server and Database in Fabric. Creating SQL Server is a simple as shown in the screenshot below:
[image]

And creating a new SQL Database is a easy as follows:

[image]

I'm struggling to understand the equivalent method of creating a SQL Server and Database in MS Fabric.

Comment: You can’t create a basic SQL Server. You have the option of creating SQL Data Warehouse, but it’s not the same, it would be a Synapse DB or Azure SQL DWH. The platform is the server. You create DWHs in the workspace.

Answer (score 0):

MSFT Fabric as of today doesnt have any feature of Azure SQL database creation.
You can create a warehouse :
[image]

But there is a mirror function coming in fabric with Azure SQL database as source but is in private preview as of today :
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-mechanics-blog/microsoft-fabric-data-mirroring-and-copilot-updates/ba-p/3989633

Comment: Hi @Nandan, this mirror function would be most helpful. Do you have any idea when the feature will become GA? Thanks

Comment: Hi @Patterson , you would have to discuss with MSFT product team for the timelines. I dont have any idea w.r.t that

Comment: Hi @Patterson, as per this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77846657/why-i-cannot-see-mirroring-sheet-in-microsoft-fabrics/77847906#77847906 the feature should be in 2024 Q1 i.e. within the next couple of months.... Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi @Nandan, thanks for this update. I was about to reach out to MS to find out exactly when this feature was going to be available. I look forward to this feature becoming GA because at the moment, I'm having to use my Azure SQL DB. I absolutely don't want to spending large amounts of money on a Fabric Warehouse when I only need a simple SQL DB. Thanks

Comment: Glad that this helped!!